# C# - Identify the matching character when using String.Split(CharArray)

Tags: c#, split

If I use the `Split()` function on a string, passing in various split characters as a `char[]` parameter, and given that the matching split character is removed from the string, how can I identify which character it matched & split on?

```
string inputString = "Hello, there| world";
char[] splitChars = new char[] { ',','|' }
foreach(string section in inputString.Split(splitChars))
{
   Console.WriteLine(section) // [0] Hello [1} there [2] world (no splitChars)
}
```

I understand that perhaps its not possible to retain this information with my approach. If thats the case, could you suggest an alternative approach?

Comment: Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I don't understand the question, where is splitChars used here? As I remember, if you use split() with no parameters, it will split each character individually.

Comment: probably it  is a typo, and he wanted to pass splitChars to split() call

Comment: @A.JAlhorr if you don't pass anything it it splits on whitespace characters like space and tab.

Comment: @IanMercer that's exactly what's needed here I guess. Post it as an answer.

Comment: Corrected the question, I'd accidentally forgotten to pass in the `splitChars` variable to the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Regex.Split()` method. I have wrapped this method in the following extension method that is as easy to use as `string.Split()` itself:

```
public static string[] ExtendedSplit(this string input, char[] splitChars) 
{
    string pattern = string.Join("|", splitChars.Select(x => "(" +  Regex.Escape(x.ToString()) + ")"));
    return Regex.Split(input, pattern);          
}
```

Usage:

```
string inputString = "Hello, there| world";
char[] splitChars = new char[]{',', '|'};

foreach (string result in inputString.ExtendedSplit(splitChars))
{
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", result);
}
```

Output:

```
'Hello'
','
' there'
'|'
' world'
```

Comment: I've made a slight adjustment to your code (I got a compile error but not sure if your code works in other versions?). Your answer is still valid and appreciated though, but I was trying to avoid using Regex (although not for any particular reason really...)

Comment: @Klicker the method is an extension method, it has to be declared in a static class.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. And I think this is the most suitable answer for what I need (I'll give in to Regex). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The C# `Regex.Split()` method documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split?view=netframework-4.7.2) can return the split characters as well as the words between them.

```
string inputString = "Hello, there| world";
string pattern = @"(,)|([|])";
foreach (string result in Regex.Split(inputString, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", result);
}
```

the result is:

```
'Hello'
','
' there'
'|'
' world'
```

Answer (score 2):

No, but its rather trivial to write one yourself. Remember, framework methods aren't magic, somebody wrote them. If something doesn't exactly match your needs, write one that does!

```
static IEnumerable<(string Sector, char Separator)> Split(
    this string s,
    IEnumerable<char> separators,
    bool removeEmptyEntries)
{
    var buffer = new StringBuilder();
    var separatorsSet = new HashSet<char>(separators);

    foreach (var c in s)
    {
        if (separatorsSet.Contains(c))
        {
            if (!removeEmptyEntries || buffer.Length > 0)
                yield return (buffer.ToString(), c);

            buffer.Clear();
        }
        else
            buffer.Append(c);
    }

    if (buffer.Length > 0)
        yield return (buffer.ToString(), default(char));
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution, however I was hoping to use this code in a class library, and using `ValueTuple` requires additional packages to be installed which I'd rather avoid.

Comment: @Klicker If you multi-target your library you can avoid this extra package for NET472 onwards as it's in the framework now. You could also use `Span<T>` to avoid the allocation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814808.aspx).